# Disabling EF table creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my application I am using EF6 to map into an existing database where I do not have control of the schema.

When the first Db call is made I get an exception where create table is not allowed, which its not and database initialisation should be disabled.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'ADatabase'.
```

I have followed various methods of disabling initialisation using both code and config but none seem to be working.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606

I have tried implementing `DbConfiguration` for auto discovery, explicitly calling it in my `Application_Start` as well as `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` in the ctor for the Context.

Config was set as per **Database Initializers** in the MSDN article linked above (sample below)

```
<contexts> 
  <context type=" Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly" disableDatabaseInitialization="true" /> 
</contexts>
```

Using EF 6.1.3, .NET 4.6 and SQL Server 2008

Comment: Try setting: `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` in your app startup.

Comment: @AjayGupta nope same error :(

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17958301/9676724)

Comment: Same error, it's still trying to create a table.